# Is it possible to include actual data on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

Is it possible to attach an example data set into this forum? I realise it is possible to provide a sample code for your data and also possible to copy and paste some of the data into the question section but is there a way of showing your actual data as a text file, such as with importing an image?

Comment: but my data consists of thousands of observations

Comment: The OP is a user on [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/faq).

Answer (score 4):

You cannot attach anything to your posts, but they may contain links to images or external sites.

If you want to insert text data, copy-and-paste the text into the question and indent it by four spaces with the `{}` button. It will retain its formatting and you can lay it out however you like.

By adding a `<!-- language: lang-none -->` tag you can prevent the syntax highlighter from incorrectly colouring parts of it.

The text will render as a scrolling pane, preventing a large blob of data from causing the question to become unreadably long.

As an example, here is a list of national capitals:

```
1    Japan  Tokyo (de facto)    13,185,502[1]
2    South Korea    Seoul   10,464,051[2]
3    Russia     Moscow  10,126,424[3]
4    Iran   Tehran  9,110,347[4]
5    Mexico     Mexico City     8,841,916[5]
6    Indonesia  Jakarta     8,489,910
7    Colombia   Bogotá  7,866,160
8    China  Beijing     7,741,274[6]
9    Egypt  Cairo   7,438,376
10   United Kingdom     London  7,287,555
11   Peru   Lima    7,220,971
12   Iraq   Baghdad     7,216,040 [7]
13   Hong Kong (China)  Hong Kong   6,752,001
14   Thailand   Bangkok     6,542,751
15   Bangladesh     Dhaka   6,080,671
16   Saudi Arabia   Riyadh  5,318,636
17   Chile  Santiago    5,012,973
18   Turkey     Ankara  4,431,719
19   Singapore  Singapore   4,408,220
20   Democratic Republic of the Congo   Kinshasa    4,385,264
21   Syria  Damascus    3,500,000
22   Germany    Berlin  3,405,250[6]
23   Vietnam    Hanoi   3,398,889[8]
24   Spain  Madrid  3,232,463
25   North Korea    Pyongyang   3,144,005
26   Afghanistan    Kabul   3,140,853
27   Argentina  Buenos Aires    3,021,865
28   Ethiopia   Addis Ababa     2,737,479
29   Kenya  Nairobi     2,665,657
30   Republic of China (Taiwan)     Taipei  2,619,920
31   Brazil     Brasília    2,606,885
32   Jordan     Amman   2,600,603
33   Ukraine    Kiev    2,591,277
34   Italy  Rome    2,503,056
35   Angola     Luanda  2,453,779
36   South Africa   Pretoria    2,345,908
37   Cuba   Havana  2,236,837[6]
38   Uzbekistan     Tashkent    2,207,850
39   France     Paris   2,103,674
40   Romania    Bucharest   1,942,254[9]
41   Azerbaijan     Baku    1,879,251
42   Dominican Republic     Santo Domingo   1,875,453
43   Venezuela  Caracas     1,838,939
44   Morocco    Rabat   1,789,635
45   Sudan  Khartoum    1,740,661
46   Hungary    Budapest    1,728,718
47   Poland     Warsaw  1,706,724
48   Belarus    Minsk   1,702,061
49   Philippines    Manila  1,660,714
50   Uganda     Kampala     1,659,600
51   Ghana  Accra   1,640,507
52   Cameroon   Yaoundé     1,616,000 [10]
53   Madagascar     Antananarivo    1,613,375[6]
54   Lebanon    Beirut  1,574,387
55   Austria    Vienna  1,552,789
56   Algeria    Algiers     1,518,083
57   Ecuador    Quito   1,504,991
58   Zimbabwe   Harare  1,487,028
59   Yemen  Sana'a  1,431,649
60   Guinea     Conakry     1,399,981
61   Malaysia   Kuala Lumpur    1,381,830
62   Uruguay    Montevideo  1,369,797
63   Zambia     Lusaka  1,331,254
64   Somaliland     Hargeisa    1,300,000
65   Mali   Bamako  1,289,626
66   Haiti  Port-au-Prince  1,235,227
67   Czech Republic     Prague  1,227,332
68   Libya  Tripoli     1,184,045
69   Kuwait     Kuwait City     1,171,880
70   Serbia     Belgrade    1,154,589
71   Somalia    Mogadishu   1,097,133
72   Bulgaria   Sofia   1,090,295
73   Congo  Brazzaville     1,088,044
74   Belgium    Brussels    1,080,790[11]
75   Armenia    Yerevan     1,080,487[6]
76   Mozambique     Maputo  1,076,689
77   Sierra Leone   Freetown    1,070,200
78   Georgia    Tbilisi     1,044,993
79   Senegal    Dakar   1,030,594
80   Burkina Faso   Ouagadougou     1,005,231
81   Ireland    Dublin  1,045,769
82   Liberia    Monrovia    1,010,970
83   Guatemala  Guatemala City  1,103,865 [12]
84   Pakistan   Islamabad   955,629
85   Nicaragua  Managua     926,883
86   Myanmar    Naypyidaw[13]   925,000[14]
87   Mongolia   Ulan Bator  907,802
88   Malawi     Lilongwe    902,388
89   Canada     Ottawa  898,150[15]
90   Bolivia    La Paz  877,363
91   Kyrgyzstan     Bishkek     843,240
92   Togo   Lomé    824,738
93   Panama     Panama City     813,097
94   Nepal  Kathmandu   812,026
95   Oman   Muscat  797,000[16]
96   Niger  Niamey  794,814[17]
97   Nigeria    Abuja   778,567[18]
98   Sweden     Stockholm   770,284[17]
99   Tunisia    Tunis   767,629
100      Turkmenistan   Ashgabat    763,537
101      Chad   N'Djamena   751,288
102      Israel     Jerusalem[19]   780,200[20]
103      Netherlands    Amsterdam   740,094[17]
104      Honduras   Tegucigalpa     735,982
105      Central African Republic   Bangui  731,548
106      Greece     Athens  721,477
107      Mauritania     Nouakchott  719,167
108      Rwanda     Kigali  718,414
109      Latvia     Riga    713,016
110      Jamaica    Kingston    701,063
111      Kazakhstan     Astana  700,000 (2007 est.)[21]
112      Croatia    Zagreb  804,200[22]
113      Cambodia   Phnom Penh  1,501,725 (2010 est.)
114      United States  Washington, D.C.    601,723
115      Finland    Helsinki    596,661[23]
116      Moldova    Chişinău    794,800 [24]
117      United Arab Emirates   Abu Dhabi   585,097[25]
118      Tajikistan     Dushanbe    582,496
119      Lithuania  Vilnius     556,723
120      Gabon  Libreville  556,425
121      Eritrea    Asmara  543,707
122      Norway     Oslo    575,475
123      Portugal   Lisbon  564,657
124      El Salvador    San Salvador    521,366
125      Paraguay   Asunción    520,722
126      Macau (China)  Macau   520,400[26]
127      Macedonia  Skopje  506,926[27]
128      Denmark    Copenhagen  506,166
129      Djibouti   Djibouti (city)     475,332
130      Côte d'Ivoire  Yamoussoukro    454,929
132      Guinea-Bissau  Bissau  452,640
132      Slovakia   Bratislava  424,207
133      Puerto Rico (USA)  San Juan    421,356
134      Estonia    Tallinn     403,547[28]
135      Burundi    Bujumbura   384,461[29]
136      Bosnia and Herzegovina     Sarajevo    383,604
137      New Zealand    Wellington  381,900[30]
138      Albania    Tirana  763,634
139      South Sudan    Juba    372,410
140      Australia  Canberra    354,644[31]
141      Costa Rica     San José    328,195
142      Qatar  Al-Doha     303,429
143      India  New Delhi   292,300
144      Papua New Guinea   Port Moresby    299,396[32][unreliable source?]
145      Tanzania   Dodoma  287,200 (2002 est.)[33]
146      Laos   Vientiane   287,579
147      Cyprus     Nicosia (south)     270,000 (late 2004)[34]
148      Lesotho    Maseru  267,652[32]
149      Slovenia   Ljubljana   264,265
150      Suriname   Paramaribo  254,147
151      Namibia    Windhoek    252,721
152      Bahamas    Nassau  248,948
153      Botswana   Gaborone    225,656[35]
154      Benin  Porto-Novo  223,552[36]
155      Western Sahara     El Aaiún    194,668 (2009 est.) [37]
156      Transnistria   Tiraspol    159,163
157      Mauritius  Port Louis  147,251[38]
158      Montenegro     Podgorica   141,854
159      Bahrain    Manama  140,616
160      Guyana     Georgetown  134,599
161      Cape Verde     Praia   125,464
162      Switzerland    Berne (de facto)    121,631 [39]
163      Sri Lanka  Sri Jayawardenapura Kotte   118,556[40]
164      Iceland    Reykjavík   115,000[41]
165      Maldives   Malé    103,693
166      Bhutan     Thimphu     101,259 [40]
167      Equatorial Guinea  Malabo  100,677 [42]
168      Barbados   Bridgetown  96,578
159      New Caledonia (France)     Nouméa  89,207[43]
170      Northern Cyprus    Nicosia (north)     84,893
171      Fiji   Suva    84,410[43]
172      Swaziland  Mbabane     81,594
173      Luxembourg     Luxembourg  76,420[44]
174      Northern Mariana Islands (USA)     Saipan  62,392 (2000)[45]
175      Comoros    Moroni  60,200
176      Solomon Islands    Honiara     59,288[43]
177      East Timor     Dili    59,069
178      Saint Lucia    Castries    57,000[46]
179      São Tomé and Príncipe  Sao Tome    56,166
180      American Samoa (USA)   Pago Pago   52,000 (2003)[47]
181      Trinidad and Tobago    Port of Spain   50,479
182      Nagorno-Karabakh Republic  Stepanakert     49,986
183      Curaçao (Netherlands)  Willemstad  49,885 [48]
184      Abkhazia   Sukhumi     43,700
185      Samoa  Apia    39,813[49]
186      Vanuatu    Port Vila   38,000 [50]
187      Monaco     Monaco  35,986 (2011 est.)[51]
188      Gambia     Banjul  34,828
189      Kiribati   Tarawa  30,000[52]
190      Aruba (Netherlands)    Oranjestad  29,998[53]
191      Seychelles     Victoria    29,298
192      Gibraltar (UK)     Gibraltar   29,286
193      Jersey (UK)    Saint Helier    28,380
194      Brunei     Bandar Seri Begawan     28,135
195      Cayman Islands (UK)    George Town     26,798
196      Isle of Man (UK)   Douglas     26,600
197      French Polynesia (France)  Papeete     26,200 [54]
198      West Bank (Israel/PNA)     Ramallah (de facto)     25,500[55]
199      Marshall Islands   Majuro  25,400
200      Andorra    Andorra la Vella    22,884
201      Antigua and Barbuda    St. John's  22,679[56]
202      Tonga  Nukuʻalofa  22,400
203      Faroe Islands (Denmark)    Tórshavn    18,573 [57]
204      Guernsey (UK)  St. Peter Port  16,701
205      Saint Vincent and the Grenadines   Kingstown   16,031
206      Greenland (Denmark)    Nuuk (Godthåb)  15,469[58]
207      South Ossetia  Tskhinvali  15,000
208      Dominica   Roseau  14,847
209      Saint Kitts and Nevis  Basseterre  13,043 [59]
210      Belize     Belmopan    12,300[60]
211      Åland (Finland)    Mariehamn   11,296 [23]
212      United States Virgin Islands (US)  Charlotte Amalie    10,817
213      Federated States of Micronesia     Palikir     9,900
214      British Virgin Islands (UK)    Road Town   9,400
215      Grenada    St. George's    7,500
216      Malta  Valletta    6,315
217      Collectivity of Saint Martin (France)  Marigot     5,700
218      Saint Pierre and Miquelon (France)     Saint-Pierre    5,509
219      Cook Islands (NZ)  Avarua  5,445
220      Liechtenstein  Vaduz   5,248
221      San Marino     City of San Marino  4,493
222      Tuvalu     Funafuti    4,492
223      Turks and Caicos Islands (UK)  Cockburn Town   3,700
224      Saint Barthélemy (France)  Gustavia    3,000
225      Falkland Islands (UK)  Stanley     2,115 [61]
226      Svalbard (Norway)  Longyearbyen    2,075
227      Christmas Island (Australia)   Flying Fish Cove    1,493 [62]
228      Sint Maarten (Netherlands)     Philipsburg     1,338
229      Wallis and Futuna (France)     Mata-Utu    1,191
230      Anguilla (UK)  The Valley  1,169
231      Nauru  Yaren (de facto)    1,100[63]
232      Guam (USA)     Hagåtña     1,100
233      Montserrat (UK)    Brades (de facto)   1,000
234      Bermuda (UK)   Hamilton    969
235      Norfolk Island (Australia)     Kingston    880 [64]
236      Holy See   The Vatican     826 (2009 est.)[65]
237      Saint Helena, Ascension and Tristan da Cunha (UK)  Jamestown   714
238      Niue (NZ)  Alofi   616
239      Tokelau (NZ)   Nukunonu (de facto)     426
240      Palau  Ngerulmud   391
241      Cocos (Keeling) Islands (Australia)    West Island     120
242      Pitcairn Islands (UK)  Adamstown   45
243      South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands (UK)  King Edward Point   18
```

Comment: You can also just wrap the block in a `<pre>` tag.

Comment: And [here's the exact same list](http://i.stack.imgur.com/CAKUK.png)...

Comment: (@lc., just in case you don't know: when using `<pre>`, be aware one needs to HTML encode things like angle brackets. For example: data such as `< .001` then needs to be encoded as `&lt; .001`.)